# How do we know that recursion and induction are valid techniques in ZFC? How do we prove them?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I don't see which axioms would give rise to them.  Replacement uses a particular wff, so it must be of finite length, but I don't see how a finite wff can deal with all natural numbers.  People often describe recursive functions as wff, but I don't know why they are.

Comment: This is done in pretty much any set theory book

Comment: That induction is valid follows immediately from the fact that ZFC contains PA , in other words , everything PA can prove , can be proven within ZFC as well.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand how ZFC can contain PA, PA takes the recursive definition of successor as an axiom.

Comment: @Bram28 Recursion in the sense of an infinite construction, induction in the sense of a proof which proves the next member for a well-order.  Definitions of the form F(x, y) = x if y is 0, else F(x, y-1) = S(F(x,y-1)) don't make sense as a wff, as it contains itself.

Comment: See e.g. Patrick Suppes, Axiomatic set theory (Dover reprint, 1960)

Comment: ZFC can provide the definition of $0$ and successor and prove that they satisfy the axioms of PA. In that sense ZFC contains PA. Actually just Z - i.e. Zermelo set theory with neither replacement not choice is strong enough for this.

Comment: Too late to edit: "not choice" should read "nor choice" in my comment above.

Comment: @Bram28: Recursion is very much the correct term here.

Answer (score 3):

Let me point out that you did not clarify the meaning of induction and recursion: Did you mean induction on $\omega$ or transfinite induction? However, the difference does not matter in answering your question.

Before stating the main point, let me say that all answers referring to Peano arithmetic are not quite correct: The induction scheme in $\mathsf{PA}$ only guarantees induction over $\omega$ for *arithmetical* statements. However, the fact that $\omega$ allows induction shows $\omega$ is a model of $\mathsf{PA}$.

To answer your question, it would be better to provide the proof of Induction and Recursion over $\omega$. I assume you know what $\omega$ is, and its well-foundedness (i.e., every non-empty subset of $\omega$ has a minumum.)

> *Proof for Induction.* Suppose that we have $(\forall k<n\phi(k))\to \phi(n)$ for all $n<\omega$. If there is $m<\omega$ such that $\lnot\phi(m)$, then the following set is not empty:
> $$A = \{m<\omega \mid \lnot\phi(m)\}.$$
> Thus we can choose the minimum of $A$, say $m_0$. So if $k<m_0$, then $k\notin A$, which means $\phi(k)$. It shows $\phi(m_0)$, a contradiction.

> *Proof for recursion.* Suppose that $F$ is a class function, i.e., there is a formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that $\forall x \exists! y\phi(x,y)$, and let us write $F(x)=y$ instead of $\phi(x,y)$.
> We want to find a defining formula of $G$ satisfying $G(n) = F(\{(k,G(k))\mid k<n\})$.
>
> The main idea of the proof is describing $G$ with its small approximation. You can prove by induction on $n<\omega$ such that there is a *unique set* function $f$ of domain $n$ such that
> $$f(m) = F(\{(k,f(k))\mid k<m\}) \qquad\cdots\cdots\cdots \qquad (\dagger)$$
> for all $m<n$. Now consider the formula $\psi(n,y)$ defined by
> $$\psi(n,y) \equiv \exists f [\operatorname{dom} f = (n+1) \land \text{$f$ satisfies }(\dagger)\land f(n)=y].$$
> You can see that $\forall n<\omega \exists! y \psi(n,y)$, so $\psi$ defines a function, say $G$.

The above proof for recursion also gives a way to view recursive functions as formulas of the language of set theory.

Comment: "every non-empty subset of $\omega$ has an element" ... even more: every non-empty subset of $\omega$ has a least element

Comment: @GEdgar Oops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

ZFC has a single axiom postulating the existence of a certain set satisfying certain properties. It's called the [axiom of infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity), because our intuition tells us that a set satisfying those properties must be infinite. Nonetheless, that axiom is of finite length. Go read that axiom. Perhaps you'll appreciate how it expresses a certain kind of recursion very succinctly, in particular with only finitely many symbols.

By applying the axiom of infinity (and the other axioms of ZFC), one can define Peano arithmetic within ZFC, meaning one can define an object which we call the *natural numbers* and prove that it satisfies Peano's axioms. As pointed out in the comments, this is done in any set theory book, and also in that wikipedia link above.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still missing a step.  I understand axiom of infinity can give a set which implies if x is in the set, then x U {x} is in the set, but I don't see how that relates to using it in a proof.

Comment: Perhaps, then, you should attempt to read how that axiom is used in a proof. Certainly there are details, but it's used like any other axiom: it asserts the existence of a certain set satisfying certain properties; now you have that set in your hands, and you use that set in further steps of the proof.

Comment: For instance, you can read exactly how the set is used in [this paragraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity#Alternative_method) of the linked wikipedia page.

Comment: Let me amend my comment above slightly. The axiom of infinity is an *existence* axiom. And once you assert its truth, it is applied like any other existence statement whose truth has been established: you take the object whose existence has been asserted, and you use that object.

Comment: The axiom of Infinity is not quite relevant to the induction and recursion. The axiom of infinity states $\mathbb{N}$ is a set, but that is all. What is more relevant is that the set of natural numbers with the natural order is a well-order.

Comment: The axiom of infinity guarantees you that $\mathbb N$ ***exists*** (that guarantee is a bit indirect; the axiom guarantees directly that a certain kind of set exists, and from that set you construct $\mathbb N$). The formula that characterizes $\mathbb N$ is what let's you deduce that it satisfies the PA axioms and, in particular, is well-ordered.

Comment: @LeeMosher the natural numbers are still a well-ordered class that interprets PA, though, without axiom of infinity. In particular you can do recursion on the natural numbers without infinity, much as you can do recursion on the proper class of ordinals which have no hope of being a set. You just wind up with the usual subtleties with working with classes (and e.g. the lack of encapsulation in a set means we only get relative consistency of PA with ZF-inf, not an outright proof of Con(PA) in ZF-inf, like we can get in ZF.)